# electron-forge + webpack: how can the live-reload be turned off?

Tags: webpack, electron, livereload, electron-forge

I have created an Electron-App using

`yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=webpack`

By starting the dev server using 'yarn start', it automatically starts with active LiveReload.

It's not documented how to start without it.

I've been adding this to the `webpack.main.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  liveReload: false,
  hot: false,
  inline: false
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It works by adding the devServer config to the `package.json` file:

```
     "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "devServer": {
              "liveReload": false,
              "hot": false
            },
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "nodeIntegration": true,
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.js",
                  "name": "main_window"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: If you want manual refresh to work but want to disable only the auto reload, then use ```liveReload: false, hot: true```